# removing or hiding option "Add new document" for a custom document library

Tags: 2007, development, document-library

I have a custom document library that "should only allow one user" to upload/Edit documents but let everyone else to download/View it.

At the moment I got two events that are checking who is uploading documents but I don't think its the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to adjust permissions on the document library level. 
Assign "Contribute" level to that particular user and "Read" to others.